# Internal Server Error ir.attachment

Tags: python, odoo

I am using the ir.attachment module.
SO i am creating my own document and then i automatically add it to the attachment by this way:

```
filename="/opt/file.txt"
files = open(filename,'rb').read()
ir_values={

'name':"image_name",
'index_content': files,
'datas_fname': "image_name",
'type':'binary',
# 'partner_id':ids[0],
'res_model':'declaration.cnss',
'res_id':ids[0],
 }
self.pool.get('ir.attachment').create(cr,uid,ir_values,context=context)
```

And, unfortunately i have got this error:

```
  Internal Server Error

 {"message": "OpenERP WebClient Error", "code": 300, "data": {"debug":   "Client Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/opt   /openerp/v7/addons/web/http.py\", line 285, in dispatch\n r = method(self,    **self.params)\n File \"/opt/openerp/v7/addons/web/controllers/main.py\", line 1286, in saveas\n filecontent = base64.b64decode(res.get(field, ''))\n File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py\", line 73, in b64decode\n return binascii.a2b_base64(s)\nTypeError: must be string or buffer, not bool\n", "type": "client_exception"}}
```

Can anyone help please :/

Regards.

Comment: if you solved your error with given answer, than I may advice to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have older version of *werkzeug* We may see in line number 299 [addons/web/http.py](https://github.com/gisce/openerp-web/blob/master/addons/web/http.py) In your case, error throws message from their.

We may see system *werkzeug* version from below command.

```
pip show werkzeug
```

If you have older version than try to upgrade with *0.9.6* with below command.

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.9.6
```

For more about Werkzeug you may visit [Werkzeug Installtion](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706123500/http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/installation/)